# specify user for init.d

Tags: server, users, init.d

I have a init.d script that start|stops|restarts a daemon using the start-stop-daemon.

This daemon is always started as root. I want to be able to specify the user that the init.d script will use to start the daemon.

Tried using the --user option for start-stop-daemon but that is not working.

Can someone please suggest how to do this.

Comment: You might want look at /etc/init.d/functions: the daemon function already allows you to set an alternate user:

daemon --user=my_user my_cmd &>/dev/null &
This is implemented by wrapping the process invocation with runuser - more on this later.

Comment: Acutally i have a init.d script. it calles the start-stop-daemon which also allows me to set the user and group, which I am doing. For some reason this is not working though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ubuntu is converting away from sysvinit to upstart, I'd suggest that you convert your script to an upstart job in the /etc/init/ directory instead. The man page is `man 5 init`.

There are setuid and setgid items to set the user and group under which the upstart job is run.

---

Assuming your script execs another script, I suppose you can add the `su userid` command to it to change the effective uid and gid to that of its argument. I'm uncertain whether its safe to run `su` in the sysvinit script itself without it changing these for subsequent /etc/init.d/ scripts, but perhaps that's OK, too.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this. But do you know how to do this for an init.d script. I already have that script ready and I need to make this change ASAP.

Comment: Added another idea, don't know if its feasible.

Comment: Ya. Ill try the second one now. The first one didn't work for some reason. I saw the man pages for start-stop-daemon and it should work according to those pages, but didn't.